# How to join a list of tags without converting them to strings?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have 2 BeautifulSoup objects `<div class="ex_example"> aa </div>` and `<div class="ex_example"> bb </div>` and `<div class="ex_example"> cc </div>`. I want to join them to get a BeautifulSoup objects `<div class="ex_example"> aa </div> <div class="ex_example"> bb </div> <div class="ex_example"> cc </div>`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt1 = '<div class="ex_example"> aa </div>'
txt2 = '<div class="ex_example"> bb </div>'
txt3 = '<div class="ex_example"> cc </div>'

object1 = BeautifulSoup(txt1, 'html.parser')
object2 = BeautifulSoup(txt2, 'html.parser')
object3 = BeautifulSoup(txt3, 'html.parser')
```

Could you please elaborate on how to achieve my goal without converting them to strings?

Comment: You can do it with lxml instead, if that works for you.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran Please see my edit.

Comment: @JackFleeting In my entire project, I always use `'html.parser'`. I'm afraid that `lxml ` will cause instability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSobjects have an extend method.. That should help solving the issue

```
In [15]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    ...:
    ...: txt1 = '<div class="ex_example"> aa </div>'
    ...: txt2 = '<div class="ex_example"> bb </div>'
    ...:
    ...: object1 = BeautifulSoup(txt1, 'html.parser')
    ...: object2 = BeautifulSoup(txt2, 'html.parser')

In [18]: object1.extend(object2)

In [19]: object1
Out[19]: <div class="ex_example"> aa </div><div class="ex_example"> bb </div>

In [20]: str(object1)
Out[20]: '<div class="ex_example"> aa </div><div class="ex_example"> bb </div>'
```

If you have more then one, you can put them in a list and iterate over them as below:

```
In [26]: txts = ['<div class="ex_example"> aa </div>', '<div class="ex_example"> bb </div>', '<div class="ex_example"> cc </div>']

In [27]: bsObjs = [ BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser') for txt in txts]

In [28]: targetBsObj = BeautifulSoup('', 'html.parser')

In [29]: for obj in bsObjs:
    ...:     targetBsObj.extend(obj)
    ...:

In [30]: targetBsObj
Out[30]: <div class="ex_example"> aa </div><div class="ex_example"> bb </div><div class="ex_example"> cc </div>
```

Comment: You method does not work in case the list has more than 2 elements. Please see my edit.